# Map JSON value to class variable with Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to get I need to map some json values to class member variables.

[image: This is a part of result JSON from Open Weather API]

I need to get lat and lon values and in the class below.

```
public class City {

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

private String latitude;

private String longitude;

// CONSTRUCTORS

// GETTERS AND SETTERS}
```

The city name was mapped using @SerializedName but it does not work with lat and lon since it is part of coord json object.

Can I help me to discover how to map it.
I don't want put coord object in city class.

This is another example of what i need to do.

[image: this is forecast list result for an openweather map api query.]

I am creating Weather class too but i don't need to store all variables from weather array or temp array but only some values. Some values are completely unecessary. In the city example i don't want to create coord object but only store lat and lon values.

Comment: Do you want to create Model class for above json?

Comment: You have to put the coord object in your city class (also it would make sense to).  You can flatten the API by just have "getLat" and "getLon" without exposing the coordinates object.

Comment: Hello Drv and DeeV. I updated question to explain better.

Comment: I think I could something like: 
`@SerializedName("coord/lat") private String latitude;` but this not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the website [JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). This would help you make the required classes with correct annotation.

You can also use the Android Studio Plugin [GsonFormat](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654?pr=androidstudio).

Comment: Thanks! but how to create the class with only the fields i will need? Lat and Lon fields are in nested array and I wish to have it in a City class not in Coord.

Comment: You can remove the other fields accordingly. But the structure would have to remain same.

Comment: Yes but I can't get lat and lon like I can get name using `@SerializedName`.

Comment: No that wont be possible, because name is directly in the City object whereas the lat/lon is in coord object. So it wont recognize the `@SerializedName`

Comment: I tried to do it: `public class City {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("coord")
    private Coord coordinates;

    private double latitude;

    private double logitude;

    public City() {}
    public City(String name, Coord coordinates) {
        this.name = name;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.latitude = coordinates.getLatitutde();
        this.logitude = coordinates.getLongitutde();
    }` but retrofit calls only the empty constructor and this way I can't set the value to latitude and longitude fields.

Comment: The City class will be a sqlite table using dbflow after and I dont want to have Coord class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: So get the data from the HTTP request parse it using Gson which is already included in Retrofit 2 and save the object using SQLite using the getter functions.

Comment: This is the app creating SQLite tables. ![SQLite Create Tables](https://cdn.rawgit.com/7odri9o/politician_images/master/code.png). I want to do the exactly the same thing using dbflow. I and for http request and i am using retrofit I want to get only necessary fields for store in database.

Comment: Rohan Sood how do you do to have lat and lon from json above in City class without create Coord class ?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a custom deserializer. When I create retrofit I pass Gson with deserializer. and at deserialize method I get only the fields I need. `        JsonObject cityJson = json.getAsJsonObject().get("city").getAsJsonObject();

        String cityName = cityJson.get("name").getAsString();
        double latitude = cityJson.get("coord").getAsJsonObject().get("lat").getAsDouble();
        double longitude = cityJson.get("coord").getAsJsonObject().get("lon").getAsDouble();` . Rohan Sood thanks for your help.

Comment: Accept the answer :)

Comment: Rohan Sood I want to reply my question talking about my solution but it seems stack overflow does not allow the question write reply your question. I will accept your answer anyway.